# Can't connect to mysql DB with Python Pandas due to "@" in the password

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect pandas to MySQL DB to write to the tables. My dummy database credentials are:

```
db_name="ai_db_dev"
db_user="ai_db_user_dev"
db_pwd="abassc@xasas12yz"
db_host="db.rds.amazonaws.com"
db_client="mysql"
```

I am connecting to the db with fake SSL flag like this:

```
db_connection_str=db_client+"://"+db_user+":"+db_pwd+"@"+db_host+"/"+db_name
connect_args={'ssl':{'fake_flag_to_enable_tls': True},
         'port': 3306}
db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str,connect_args= connect_args)
```

and I am trying to insert the db into the table like this:

```
df.to_sql(con=db_connection, name='ai_table', if_exists='append', index= False)
```

But due to the '@' in the password, it is not picking up the host properly and hence I am unable to connect to the DB. Any help in solving this issue will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What if you url encode your password like what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23408743/5472004) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy has a built-in [URL.create()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html?highlight=url#sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create) method that will build a properly-escaped URL for you:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

db_name="ai_db_dev"
db_user="ai_db_user_dev"
db_pwd="abassc@xasas12yz"
db_host="db.rds.amazonaws.com"
db_client="mysql"

connection_url = sa.engine.URL.create(
    drivername=db_client,
    username=db_user,
    password=db_pwd,
    host=db_host,
    database=db_name
)
print(connection_url)
# mysql://ai_db_user_dev:abassc%40xasas12yz@db.rds.amazonaws.com/ai_db_dev
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enclose your username and password by simple quotes?

```
db_connection_str = f"{db_client}://'{db_user}':'{db_pwd}'@{db_host}/{db_name}"
```

```
>>> db_connection_str
"mysql://'ai_db_user_dev':'abassc@xasas12yz'@db.rds.amazonaws.com/ai_db_dev"
```

**Attempt 2**

```
from urllib.parse import quote

db_connection_str = f"{db_client}://{db_user}:{quote(db_pwd)}@{db_host}/{db_name}"
```

Output:

```
>>> db_connection_str
"mysql://'ai_db_user_dev':'abassc%40xasas12yz'@db.rds.amazonaws.com/ai_db_dev"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am getting the error "Access denied for user". Maybe the quotes changed the password or something?

Comment: I updated my answer. Try to use `quote` from `urllib.parse`.

Comment: thanks! it also solved the issue.